# What’s design style is this called that twitter uses?

Tags: style-identification, graphic-styles

[image][image]What design style that Twitter use as illustration on their app?

Comment: Not every style in graphic design has a specific name, so you can just use descriptive words. Perhaps you could call it a simulated bad registration print effect.

Comment: You can play with a split channel effect to get there... https://youtu.be/61oJUNuJK-E

Answer (score 1):

Halftone seems to be the main element. I think the idea is to simulate the immediacy of real-life posters with artefacts of printing. Wheatpaste?